# How to simply read out / save optimized variables from Gurobi

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

So, I've optimized my Gurobi model, but I can't really find a simple way to save the solutions. How do I simply save the variables (which are matrices and vectors and such)?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you've given your variables a name in the model it's really easy!

With the function `m.getVars()` you get a list of the variable name with its solution. If you then turn this information into a string in the syntax of the Python code in which you would want to execute it, you can actually execute this using `exec(string)`! It is important that you make a numpy array beforehand of the size of the variable you want to save.

So say you optimized a matrix `x` of size `n` by `m`, you do the following:

```
x = np.zeros([n,m])
for v in mo.getVars():
   print(v.varName +'='+ str(v.x))
   string = v.varName +'='+ str(v.x)
   exec(string)
```

Comment: This code makes no sense. What is `exec(string)` supposed to do and why do you need the numpy array `x` - it's never referenced?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gurobis `write()` method to write the current solution to a file. You only need to use the `.sol` filename suffix:

```py
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB

# Create a new model
m = gp.Model("mip1")

x = m.addVars(3, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x")

m.setObjective(x[0] + x[1] + 2 * x[2], GRB.MAXIMIZE)
m.addConstr(x[0] + 2 * x[1] + 3 * x[2] <= 4, "c0")
m.addConstr(x[0] + x[1] >= 1, "c1")

# Optimize model
m.optimize()

# Write the solution to a file "mip1.sol"
m.write("mip1.sol")
```

gives

```
# Solution for model mip1
# Objective value = 3
x[0] 1
x[1] 0
x[2] 1
```

Comment: what does it write then exactly?

Comment: @Britta I edited my answer. It just writes the variable names with the variable value in the current solution, as expected.

Comment: so it just prints it rather than saving the variables like that?

Comment: No, it writes it into the file mip1.sol. Feel free to try it.